# Flutter SingleChildScrollView containers are showing even if it not supposed to?

Tags: flutter, dart

The bottom side of the scrollview goes behind the buttons that are at the bottom.

As you can see for some reason if I scroll it, the containers are shown behind the buttons. The text disappears but the background color can be seen. I don't find it why it is doing it.

```
 createNotes() {
    return Container(
      decoration: borderBoxDecoration(),
      child: ListTile(
        tileColor: Colors.yellow,
        title: Text(
          "Events",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 24,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          ),
        ),
        subtitle: Text("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
          maxLines: 5,
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        ),
        onTap: () => func(),
      ),
    );
  }


  addPadding() {
    return  Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
    );
  }

 BoxDecoration borderBoxDecoration() {
    return BoxDecoration(
      border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good day!
If i understand correctly, try replace this part of code on this:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              addPadding(),
              createNotes(),
              addPadding(),
              createNotes(),
              addPadding(),
              createNotes(),
              addPadding(),
              createNotes(),
              addPadding(),
              createNotes(),
              addPadding(),
              createNotes(),
              addPadding(),
              createNotes(),
              addPadding(),
              createNotes(),
              addPadding(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('Name one'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('Name two'),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 4,
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('Name three'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

result video: https://media.giphy.com/media/OVQSeYkCEG37VT2mCX/giphy.gif

full code:
https://codeshare.io/K88jMP

Comment: Sadly no. You still can see the text containers behind the buttons: https://i.imgur.com/mzPwmZM.png